# What's going on with the two-dimensional Helmholtz equation?

Tags: green-function, laplace-equation

I've come to realize that its somehow harder to find results for this equation than for the three-dimensional one.

For example the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) on Green's functions has a list of green functions where the Green's function for both the two and three dimensional Laplace equation appear. Also the Green's function for the three-dimensional Helmholtz equation but nothing about the two-dimensional one.

The same happens in the [Sommerfield condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_radiation_condition) article. The condition is written in a generic fashion, depending on the number of dimensions $n$, but when it's time to show an example showing the solution of a point source only the three-dimensional case is shown.

Is it just a coincidence? or the solution to the point source in the two dimensional case:
$$
G\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right)=\frac{i}{4}H_0^1\left(\kappa\left\vert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\right\vert\right)
$$
is not a true Green's functions for some reason?

Comment: What is a "true" Green's function? The difference is that in more than two dimensions there is a solution of $\Delta u=\delta$ which vanishes at infinity, in two or one dimension there is not.

Comment: That was part of my question, that maybe for some reason I don't know this function I show was not considered a Green function. However, I don't know that you mean by your difference. The article in the wikipedia does indeed show a green function for the two-dimensional laplacian (which, as you say, does not vanish at infinity). But my question is why the two-dimensional Helmholtz equation is missing?

Comment: The Helmholtz equations stems from separating variables in the wave equation. [Physicists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532178/why-would-sound-reverberate-indefinitely-in-two-spatial-dimensions) are well aware that wave propagation in 2d is very different from 3d. Living in a two dimensional world we would be begging to go deaf.

Comment: Green's function for the two-dimensional Helmholtz equation is derived in this work: http://www.sbfisica.org.br/rbef/pdf/351304.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You seek the solution of
$$(\nabla^2+\kappa^2+i\epsilon)G(\mathbf{r})=\delta(\mathbf{r}),$$
in the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$, which is given by a Hankel function of the first kind,
$$G(\mathbf{r})=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int\frac{d^2\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^2}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\frac{1}{\kappa^2+i\epsilon-k^2}=\frac{1}{4i}H_0(\kappa r).$$
There is a logarithmic singularity at $r=0$, but it's a valid Green function.